# With each save to a .csv file a comma is added to the userName

Tags: java

With each iteration of the program it saves each object's variables back to a .csv file and overwrites the previous. I tried doing `read.next();` for the `userName` but that results in an error because if there is no `userName` it's meant to be empty. After 3 saves the `userName` would be `,,,Fred`. I assume it's because I'm using `.nextLine()` and it reads the `,`.

I used a delimiter to read the .csv file. `.useDelimiter(",")`

Scanner:

```
 while (read.hasNext()) {

            String ID = read.next();
            double BatteryCharge = read.nextDouble();
            boolean inUse = read.nextBoolean();
            long rentalStart = read.nextLong();
            String userName = read.nextLine();


            bikeArrayList.add(new Bike(ID, BatteryCharge, inUse, rentalStart, userName));
        }
```

PrintWriter:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bikeArrayList.size(); i++) {
            write.print(bikeArrayList.get(i).getBikeId() + ",");
            write.print(bikeArrayList.get(i).getBatteryCharge() + ",");
            write.print(bikeArrayList.get(i).isInUse() + ",");
            write.print(bikeArrayList.get(i).getRentalStart() + ",");
            write.println((bikeArrayList.get(i).getUserName());
        }
```

This is what the file saves as on the .csv file:

```
BE11,1.00,true,122123,,,,Fred
BE12,1.00,false,0,
BE13,1.00,false,0,
```

Comment: Is it readily from the keyboard or from a file?

Comment: If your IDs and usernames are not allowed to contain `,`, when reading, just read the whole line and use `String#split(",")` to get the indivual parts.

Comment: It's from a file @ChengThao

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
            String ID = read.next();
            double BatteryCharge = read.nextDouble();
            boolean inUse = read.nextBoolean();
            long rentalStart = read.nextLong();
            String userName = read.nextLine();
            userName = userName.replace(",","");
```

Comment: Why the need to replace "," with ""?  If you read correctly, userName should contains the user name, not comma.  Can you provide the format of your data in the input file?

Comment: Can you provide your Bike class and the content of your input file (even if only a few lines)?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).